# A question on integrability of harmonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, potential-theory

Suppose $D$ is a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ ($m>1$). If $h$ is harmonic on $D$, do we have 
$$\int_{D}|h(x)|dx<\infty?$$

Comment: I've never about a result that says that harmonic function are $L^1$. So, I would say no. But...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not. In $\mathbb R^3$let $D=\{0<|x|<1\}.$ The function $h(x) = |x|^{-1}$ is harmonic in $D.$ Hence all derivatives of $h$ are harmonic in $D.$ But $$\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x_1^2}$$
 fails the integrability condition.